# Virtualbox Fails to start with ERROR_SERVICE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT

Tags: virtualbox

Yet another 'virtualbox fails to start question', this time with a new COM error. This is on Windows 10 Pro, where I've been running various versions of virtualbox without issue over the years.

I tried to install the latest (at the time of writing) - `VirtualBox-7.0.8-156879-Win.exe`, but it keeps failing to start.

I've tried the basics - various combinations of uninstall/re-install with and without running as admin.
I've also tried deleting the `.VirtualBox` folder in `C:\users\[user name]`.

When I try to start Virtualbox, I'm presented with this error:

```
Failed to acquire the VirtualBox COM object.

The application will now terminate.



Completely failed to instantiate CLSID_VirtualBox: ERROR_SERVICE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT/0x8007041d.

Result Code:ERROR_SERVICE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT/0x8007041d (0X8007041D)
Component:VirtualBoxClientWrap
Interface:IVirtualBoxClient {d2937a8e-cb8d-4382-90ba-b7da78a74573}
```

I've confirmed the `VirtualBox system service` is using a local system account (I've even tried changing this to Administrator, but that fails with a warning that its not meant to run as administrator).

When I try to start the Virtualbox system service manually, it times out. Looking in the event log, I see an event ID 10005 from DistributedCom with the following:

```
DCOM got error "1053" attempting to start the service VBoxSDS with arguments "Unavailable" in order to run the server:
{74AB5FFE-8726-4435-AA7E-876D705BCBA5}
```

I'm hoping some virtualbox guru out there might have some ideas?

Comment: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=101493

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1548880/368970

Comment: @YisroelTech - The error in that Super User question is an entirely different error.

Comment: @andrew-g-za - When you installed VirtualBox did you install it as an Administrator (i.e. `run as Administrator`)?

Comment: In *Start > Turn Windows features on or off*, disable: Windows Hypervisor Platform, Virtual Machine Platform, Hyper-V. Reboot. If it still not working, enable Virtual Machine Platform and reboot.

Comment: The current version of VirtualBox running on Windows 10 22H2 or Windows 11 22H2 should fully support both VPM and Hyper-V being installed.  There shold be no compatability issues with both of those optional windows features being installed.

Comment: @Ramhound - yes, I tried running the installer both as Administrator and not.

Comment: The only result I found related to this particular error suggests the problem is caused by. Windows installation that isn’t healthy and one that should be repaired.

Comment: @harrymc - thanks - those settings are already off

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound - I've tried a repair (via sfc.exe) - it reported no issues. I've also tried installing virtualbox 6.1.44 - same issue.

Comment: Try : Uninstall VirtualBox, reboot in Safe mode, install VirtualBox, reboot normally. If the problem is still there : Run VirtualBox as Administrator, exit it, then run it normally.

Comment: @andrew-g-za - SFC is the wrong tool. You would have to use DISM or perform and in-place repair installation of the same version your using.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound - I did run DSIM before sfc

Comment: Thanks @harrymc - will give that a shot too

Comment: @harrymc - running installers in safe mode is prevented. I've tried running Virtualbox as Administrator before with no luck - thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: I don't understand why the installer doesn't run - perhaps you need Safe mode with network? If you can't manage it in Safe mode, try at least to disable in your antivirus the real-time protection during the installation.